# Linq query “where [column] in (list of values)” that return single value for each values?

Tags: c#, linq

Let say we have this LinQ code (in LinqPad):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("1611080010");
list.Add("1611080011");
list.Add("WRONGID");

var result = Orders.AsQueryable().Where(y => list.Contains(y.Id));
// And yes my Ids are string for this sample
result.Dump(); // To display the result in LinqPad
result.Count(); // equal 2
```

Is it possible to improve this query to force the system to return one element for each of my list element or throw an exception? So if I have 3 values in my list I should have 3 values in my result?

Comment: If you want to be efficient, your list should really be a Hashset instead so that Contains is O(1) rather than O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your question: **Is it possible to improve this query to force the system to return one element for each of my list element or throw an exception:**

```
var result = Orders.AsQueryable().SingleOrDefault(y => list.Contains(y.Id));
```

[**SingleOrDefault**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more
>   than one element in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  any one from below one

Whenever you use SingleOrDefault, you clearly state that the query should result in at most a single result. On the other hand, when FirstOrDefault is used, the query can return any amount of results but you state that you only want the first one.

I personally find the semantics very different and using the appropriate one, depending on the expected results, improves readability.

```
var result = Orders.AsQueryable().SingleOrDefault(y => list.Contains(y.Id));

var result = Orders.AsQueryable()..FirstOrDefault(y => list.Contains(y.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to return one object from `Orders` where the Id of the object equals an Id in your `list` and if an Id in the `list` is not present in the `Orders` object  an exception should be thrown.

To achieve that you could do:

```
var result = list.Select(id => Orders.AsQueryable().First(y => y.Id == id)).ToList();
```

This will throw an exception if an Id from the `list` has no match in the `Orders` object. If all Ids are found then your `result` will contain the same number of elements as there are Ids in the `list`.

Another option would be to use:

```
var result = list.Select(id => Orders.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == id)).ToList();
```

This would not throw an error, but it would always return the same number of elements as there are Ids in the `list`. The Ids that would not be found would have a `null` entry though.